# Matlab read multiples samples with audioread

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to read multiple samples from a mp3 file with the function audioread.

let's say I have the following code :

```
samples = [1, 44100; 50000, 100000; 150000, 200000];
[signal, fe] = audioread(filepath, samples);
t = (1/fe:1/fe:lenght(signal)/fe);
signal = signal(:,1);
```

How can I make this work ? If samples contain only 1 row, it works just fine, but I have like 80 samples in the same mp3 file to work with.

I've tried this with a for loop, the audioread part works fine, but I don't know how to store the data since the duration of each sample isn't the same, the dimensions of matrices are not consistent and I can't concatenate them in a single matrix.

Plus, I've been told for loops are better avoided whenever possible in Matlab, so I'd like to do this by the rules (but i'll use them if there's no other way ofc).

Finally I'm very new to Matlab so I might miss something very obvious, but cound'nt find out reading through the doc.

Thks for your help :)

Comment: Look up cell arrays

Comment: Yay, I can store data now, thks. Can I also use it to avoid making a loop or not ?

Comment: Loops may be necessary in this case and aren't always evil. If you have performance issues *then* consider removing them